# Returning condition error to simpleRestProvider

Tags: react-admin

I'm using simpleRestProvider in a React Admin application and I was wondering if there's a way to return an error message to the application and have it displayed? Currently the errors it shows are things like server error and the like which aren't not helpful.

Basically I want the successful behavior to continue as-is and a failure messge to be shown as a dialogue

Answer (score 1):

If your dataProvider returns a failed Promise with an Error object with a `message` property, react-admin renders this message in the notification instead of the default message (see https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviderWriting.html#error-format for details).

The Simple Rest Data provider normally already does this if your backend returns a body with a JSON object containing a `message` key:

```json
{
   "message": "you cannot do that"
}
```